# Программное создание fragment с конкретным linearlayout

Tags: android, android-fragment

Добрый день!

Моя программа считывает сообщение и в зависимости от его содержания создаёт несколько LinearLayout'ов с различным заполнением.

Возможно ли программное создание фрагмента с одним из полученных LinearLayout'ов (количество фрагментов = количеству лайаутов и конечное число заранее неизвестно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте такой метод во фрагменте:

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(int layout) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("layout", layout);
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

Далее напишите в `onCreateView`:

```
int layout = getArguments().getInt("layout", 0)
View v = inflater.inflate(layout, container, false);
return v;
```

вызывать где нужно `MyFragment fragment = MyFragment.newInstance(my_layout);`

Либо, например, передавать во фрагмент какое-то число, которое во фрагменте, в зависимости от значения (`switch(getArguments().getInt("number,0))`), будет загружать нужный `layout`.